# Eliminating Memory Leak in C++

Tags: c++

I have created a function named substring and used it in the following way:-

```
char* substring(char* source, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int size = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
    char* s = new char[size+1];
    strncpy(s, source + startIndex, size);
    s[size]  = '\0';
    return s;
}

char *game1 = new char[10]
char* a0 = substring(csv, 0, x[0]);
game1 = a0;
//delete[] a0;
delete[] game1;
```

But, it is causing some memory leak after checking it through Valgrind. When I delete a0, the program doesn't work. How can I deal with this problem? Thanks.

I have made an edit:-

```
char* game1 = substring(csv, 0, x[0]);
delete[] game1;
```

Comment: Discuss with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what happened to the `new char[10]` between  `char *game1 = new char[10]` and `game1 = a0;`.  Did you need it at all?

Comment: You have two `new`s and one `delete`. Think about how that could possibly be right.

Comment: *How can I deal with this problem?* -- Use `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the game1 dynamic array as well but, still, doesn't work

Comment: `game1 = a0;` -- As soon as you did this, your program becomes broken.  You have a memory leak.

Comment: Use a debugger or a few print statements to see where `game1` points when you `delete[] game1;`.

Comment: I have made an edit, but, it is still causing memory leak due to game1

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing what you are doing.  And quite honestly, what if your real code requires so many patches and fixes and hoop jumping to get it to not leak memory?  That's why `std::string` was created.

Comment: What is in `x[0]`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone I found the error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is near
 `char *game1 = new char[10]`
You have assigned char[10] to game1 which you never deleted.

Try by adding
 `delete[] game1;`

before

```
game1 = a0;
```

Actually you don't need to assign that char[10] to game1 I don't know why you have done it. Removing that may also work.
Just declaring as

```
char *game1;
```

Comment: @tadman look at code he assigned char[10] to game1 that address he never used. Can you tell how it   substring pointer references a deleted structure

Comment: Oh, I see, that comes from `x`, not `game1`. I'm not even sure what that allocation is doing there then if you just up and delete it without using it.

Comment: Sorry, this code is just so confused that I didn't notice that. You're right, though to the point that `char* game1 = substring(...)` is probably the best way since, apparently, this `substring` method does allocation.